# Python file quits immediately after input

Tags: python

I have been trying to get this program to work for about 30 minutes now, but every time I run the file, it quits itself after any kind of input.
I don't know exactly where the issue is, so I will post all of the code.
Here is what I have so far:

```
import os, time

os.system("color")
loading = 0
logged = 0
r = "r"
l = "l"
COLOR = {
    "PURPLE": "\033[95m",
    "BLUE": "\033[0;34m",
    "GREEN": "\033[0;32m",
    "RED": "\033[91m",
    "GRAY": "\033[0;39m",
    "CYAN": "\033[0;36m",
    "CLR": "\033[0m",
}

print(COLOR["GRAY"], "starting", COLOR["CLR"], "\bSh", COLOR["CYAN"], "\b\bi", COLOR["CLR"], "\b\bftOS...")

while loading <= 10:
    for rod in r'--//||\\':
        print(rod, rod, rod, rod, rod, rod, rod, rod, rod, rod, rod, end='\r')
        time.sleep(0.05)
        loading = loading + 1
###############################
yesno = input("register or login? (r/l) -> ")
if yesno == r:  register_a()
if yesno == l:  log_in()


# if yesno != "r" and yesno != "l": quit()
def register_a():
    print(COLOR["BLUE"], "\n\n new username: ", COLOR["CLR"])
    username = input("->  ")
    print(COLOR["RED"], "\n\n new password: ", COLOR["CLR"])
    password = input("->  ")
    print("writing credentialz.txt file..")

    f = open("credentialz.txt", "w")
    f.write(username)
    f.close()
    f = open("credentialz.txt", "a")
    f.write(password)
    f.close
    return username, password


def log_in():
    f = open("credentialz.txt", "a")
    a = f.readline()
    b = f.readline()
    f.close
    useratt = input("USERNAME: ")
    passatt = input("PASSWORD: ")
    f = open("credentialz.txt", "r")
    if useratt == a and passatt == b:
        print(COLOR["BLUE"], "LOGGED IN SUCCESSFULLY!", COLOR["CLR"])
        logged = 1
    else:
        print(COLOR["RED"], "WRONG USERNAME/PASSWORD!", COLOR["CLR"])
```

I am using python 3.9 on Windows 10.

Answer (score 0):

In `log_in()` function, try writing `f.close()`. You've missed the parentheses.